# Python, read every text file that starts with Output

Tags: python

So i have a script that filters certain words from a text file, but is it possible that it filters certain words from like 3 text files that start with a certain name? As example:

```
import fileinput 
import time

bad_words = ['1', '2', '3']

with open(Everyfile that starts with Output) as badfile, open('Output2.txt', 'w') as cleanfile:
    for line in badfile:
        clean = True
        for word in bad_words:
            if word in line:
                clean = False
        if clean == True:
            cleanfile.write(line)
print('Finished')
time.sleep(3)
```

There wont be any other text files in the directory so if thats not possible, would it be possible to read every file that is a text file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Path.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) from `pathlib` module you can filter the files then using a loop you can filter the lines containing bad words.

```
from pathlib import Path

bad_words = ['1', '2', '3']

with open('results.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for file in Path('directory_path').glob('Output*.txt'):
        for line in file.open().readlines():
            if all(word not in line for word in bad_words):
                fw.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use globbing for getting all the bad "Output" files, then loop over them to create their corresponding "Clean" files:

```
import time
import glob

bad_words = ['1', '2', '3']

# Create a file to test on
with open("Outputfile.txt", 'w') as wf:
    for word in bad_words:
        wf.write(word)

output_files = glob.glob("Output*", recursive=True)

# And to get all text files:
# text_files = glob.glob("*.txt", recursive=True)

for file in output_files:
    with open(file) as badfile, open('Output2.txt', 'w') as cleanfile:
        for line in badfile:
            clean = True
            for word in bad_words:
                if word in line:
                    clean = False
            if clean == True:
                cleanfile.write(line)
    print('Finished')
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
file_list =["badfile1", "bad_alsofile","goodfile"] #list of files
bad_list = [p for p in file_list if p.startswith("bad")] #Get badfiles
#bad_list = ["badfile1","bad_alsofile"]
```

gives a list of the "bad" files

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` for dealing with files in the file system easily. In this case, you use the method `Path(".").glob("Output*")` to find all files in the current directory that start with `Output`

```py
import fileinput
import time
import pathlib

bad_words = ['1', '2', '3']

with open('Output2.txt', 'w') as cleanfile:
    for badfile in pathlib.Path(".").glob("Output*"):
        with badfile.open() as badfile:
            for line in badfile:
                clean = True
                for word in bad_words:
                    if word in line:
                        clean = False
                if clean == True:
                    cleanfile.write(line)

print('Finished')
time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,glob
path1='FolderPath'
for file in glob.glob(path1+"*Output*.txt"):
    with open(file) as badfile, open('Output2.txt', 'w') as cleanfile:
        for line in badfile:
            clean = True
            for word in bad_words:
                if word in line:
                    clean = False
            if clean == True:
                cleanfile.write(line)
```

Try This.
It will open all the file in given folder which contains "Output" in filename.